# query with native where clause not work fine

Tags: spring, oracle, native

I'm Using oracle DB with Spring boot and i write a query in a table with 88 million records it's take 5 minutes to return answer and not working where clause . this is my query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM NUSSDFINANCIALSTR1 WHERE "+
            ":startd IS NULL or TMST BETWEEN :startd and :endd AND "+
            ":phone  IS NULL or PHONE = :phone  AND "+
            ":destphone  IS NULL or  DESTPHONE = :destphone  AND "+
            ":amount  IS NULL or AMONT = :amount  AND "+
            ":bres  IS NULL or BRES = :bres  AND "+
            ":tres  IS NULL or TRES = :tres AND ROWNUM <=100 order by TMST DESC",
            nativeQuery = true)
```

where I call the method and call query my parameters passed true but in return field 'tmst' not work true and amount and phone , all of parameter that i passed it's return all of record in table and don't compare with my param

Comment: Add brackets to identify how those OR and AND conditions relate

Comment: I added the bracket but i get `ORA-00936: missing expression` error i added like this: 'SELECT * FROM NUSSDFINANCIALSTR1 WHERE "+
            "[:startd IS NULL] or [TMST BETWEEN :startd and :endd AND ]"+
            "[:phone IS NULL] or [PHONE = :phone AND ]"+
            "[:destphone IS NULL] or [DESTPHONE = :destphone AND ]"+
            "[:amount IS NULL] or [AMONT = :amount AND ]"+
            "[:bres IS NULL] or [BRES = :bres AND ]"+
            "[:tres IS NULL] or [TRES = :tres AND] ROWNUM <=100 order by TMST DESC'

Comment: that should be parenthesis not brackets

Comment: write above only last clause in query  work fine and other clause in query not work and return all of record in oracle : 
 ' @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM NUSSDFINANCIALSTR1  WHERE "+
            "(:startd IS NULL) or (TMST BETWEEN :startd and :endd) AND "+
            "(:phone  IS NULL) or (PHONE = :phone) AND "+
            "(:destphone  IS NULL) or (DESTPHONE = :destphone) AND "+
            "(:amount  IS NULL) or (AMONT = :amount) AND "+
            "(:bres  IS NULL) or (BRES = :bres) AND "+
            "(:tres  IS NULL) or (TRES = :tres)",
            nativeQuery = true) '